# Do big JS-Files have an impact on the performance (in local files)?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with a lot JS-Functions in LOCAL files.

I currently wonder if it is worth the effort to load the files dynamically only when needed. The dynamic loading would surely create some overhead and I wonder if it even matters.

All JS-Code is wrapped into functions that are only called when needed.

The JSes are about 500KB of Data.

So: Do loaded but uncalled JS-functions matter?

Comment: Use the browser performance tools to determine how long it's taking for the files to be loaded and interpreted.

Comment: The chrome extension modifies the Google+ - Site, which is constantly loading data and modifying the dom itself. So, performance measueres do not work that well here